# Webpack 5 Terser: How can I require 'uglify-module'

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler, minify

I'm trying to use TerserPlugin to minify my code, I found this snippet below in their official docs:

```
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          myCustomOption: true,
        },
        minify: (file, sourceMap, minimizerOptions) => {
          const extractedComments = [];
          const { map, code } = require("uglify-module").minify(file, {});
          return { map, code, extractedComments };
        },
      }),
    ],
  }
```

> but after adding this snippet I'm getting an error: `Error: Cannot find module 'uglify-module'`

also, this 'uglify-module' can't be found on npm registry.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `uglify-js` instead of `uglify-module`

Answer (score 1):

`uglify-module` is meant as a placeholder, it means "require one of the modules that works the way uglify does", since there's more than one option there. You don't actually need to implement the `minify` function at all though. From the docs:

> Allows you to override default minify function. By default plugin uses terser package. Useful for using and testing unpublished versions or forks.

So unless you have very specific needs for the minification, you should not override that.